# Функции работы с файлами c++

Tags: функции, fopen

fopen и open разница в c++. Не могу понять.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: fopen - это сишная функция. open - это скорее всего низкоуровневая функция ОС. А в с++ - fstream.

Answer (score 1):

На английском СО [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open), что `open` - это низкоуровневая функция, уровня ОС, а `fopen` - это более высокоуровневая надстройка с буферизацией и прочими плюшками, а также она совместима со стандартами и переносима, поэтому рекомендуют использовать `fopen`.

Comment: Довольно очевидно, но выбор между `fopen()/open()` зависит от сути конкретной задачи. Например, 1) нам не нужен переносимый повсюду код: 2) требуется прочесть весь файл в память; Решение -- однозначно **open()** (ну, зачем лишний раз копировать байтики). А вот если мы хотим читать файл построчно, то тут (не писать же самим буферизацию, которую сотни раз уже реализовывали до нас) берем **fopen()**